# Silverlight: What is the easiest way to display disabled icons in silverlight

Tags: silverlight-4.0

In JS I would just change the resource url for the image. Is there a way in SL4 to apply some effect to image to make it grayish or something to indicate that command is disabled? Images are in png format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every `Control` within in Silvelright has an [IsEnabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.isenabled%28VS.95%29.aspx) property. This can be used to define an enabled/disabled state which can then be styled as such in XAML (layer over the button to signal it is disabled for instance). `Image` however does not derive from `Control` and therefore does not have the `IsEnabled` property.

You could either create a custom `Image` class which will take care of applying the said behavior making use of the [VisualStateManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.visualstatemanager%28VS.95%29.aspx).

You could also create a custom `UserControl` which can encapsulate the behavior you are looking for; making use of the two images and switching between them based on an exposed property; ie...IsEnabled.

You could also go the [Image.Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.source%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) route as you have done in JS which will change out the image being displayed; pushing the logic elsewhere and then changing out the source in code behind.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could wrap the image within a hyperlink control (assuming you need to handle a click event), and set the hyperlink's IsEnabled property:

```
<HyperlinkButton x:Name="btnSave" Click="btnSave_Click" IsEnabled="False">
    <Image Source="/YourNamespace;component/Images/Icons/Save.png" Stretch="Fill"/>
</HyperlinkButton>
```